# Stanford Relationship training not working

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to run the relationship trainer as specified at the URL http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml However, it is not able to find the tagger although I have specified the stanford-postagger.jar in the classpath. Any pointers in the right direction on this would be very helpful.

I am running on Windows on the command prompt as given below:

> D:\01.Jars\Jars_Stanford\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20>java -cp
>   "stanford-ner .jar;stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar;stanford-postagger.jar"
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.mach inereading.MachineReading --arguments
>   SuperAnnuation.properties PERCENTAGE OF TRAIN: 1.0 The reader log
>   level is set to SEVERE Adding annotator pos Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.Runti meIOException:
>   Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactor
>   ies.java:292)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.j
>   ava:289)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java
>   :126)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeMachineReading(
>   MachineReading.java:228)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.main(MachineReading
>   .java:106) Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException:
>   Unrecoverable error while loa ding a tagger model
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTa
>   gger.java:770)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:
>   298)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.(MaxentTagger.java:
>   263)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnot
>   ator.java:97)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.(POSTaggerAnnotato
>   r.java:77)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(Annotato
>   rImplementations.java:59)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactor
>   ies.java:290)
>           ... 5 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-t
>   agger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as either
>   class path , filename or URL
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSys
>   tem(IOUtils.java:481)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTa
>   gger.java:765)
>           ... 11 more

And the Superannuation Property file used is given below. This is the default property file provided on the website:

```
#Below are some basic options. See edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReadingProperties class for more options.

# Pipeline options
annotators = pos, lemma, parse
parse.maxlen = 100

# MachineReading properties. You need one class to read the dataset into correct format. See edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.ace.AceReader for another example.
datasetReaderClass = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothCONLL04Reader

#Data directory for training. The datasetReaderClass reads data from this path and makes corresponding sentences and annotations.
trainPath = /u/nlp/data/RothCONLL04/conll04.corp

#Whether to crossValidate, that is evaluate, or just train.
crossValidate = false
kfold = 10

#Change this to true if you want to use CoreNLP pipeline generated NER tags. The default model generated with the relation extractor release uses the CoreNLP pipeline provided tags (option set to true).
trainUsePipelineNER=false

# where to save training sentences. uses the file if it exists, otherwise creates it.
serializedTrainingSentencesPath = tmp/roth_sentences.ser

serializedEntityExtractorPath = tmp/roth_entity_model.ser

# where to store the output of the extractor (sentence objects with relations generated by the model). This is what you will use as the model when using 'relation' annotator in the CoreNLP pipeline.
serializedRelationExtractorPath = tmp/roth_relation_model_pipeline.ser

# uncomment to load a serialized model instead of retraining
# loadModel = true

#relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter,edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothResultsByRelation. For printing output of the model.
relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter

#In this domain, this is trivial since all the entities are given (or set using CoreNLP NER tagger).
entityClassifier = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.roth.RothEntityExtractor

extractRelations = true
extractEvents = false

#We are setting the entities beforehand so the model does not learn how to extract entities etc.
extractEntities = false

#Opposite of crossValidate. 
trainOnly=true

# The set chosen by feature selection using RothCONLL04:
relationFeatures = arg_words,arg_type,dependency_path_lowlevel,dependency_path_words,surface_path_POS,entities_between_args,full_tree_path

# The above features plus the features used in Bjorne BioNLP09:
# relationFeatures = arg_words,arg_type,dependency_path_lowlevel,dependency_path_words,surface_path_POS,entities_between_args,full_tree_path,dependency_path_POS_unigrams,dependency_path_word_n_grams,dependency_path_POS_n_grams,dependency_path_edge_lowlevel_n_grams,dependency_path_edge-node-edge-grams_lowlevel,dependency_path_node-edge-node-grams_lowlevel,dependency_path_directed_bigrams,dependency_path_edge_unigrams,same_head,entity_counts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run with the full Stanford CoreNLP jar, and the associated models jar. These can both be downloaded from the [CoreNLP downloads page](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html). Make sure to include both the code jar and the models jar in your classpath!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am running with the full set of code and model jars but still getting the error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Gabor Angeli for the comment. I modified the command and it works now.        `java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar;C:\jars\jars_stanford\stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20\stanford-postagger-3.5.2.jar;C:\jars\jars_stanford\stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20\models\english-left3words-distsim.tagger;  edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading --arguments roth.properties`